# Polymorphic types with purescript-bridge

Tags: haskell, purescript

I have type in Haskell

```
newtype Uid a = Uid {uidToText :: Text}
  deriving (Eq, Ord, Show, Data, Typeable, Generic)
```

Using `purescript-bridge` library `mkSumType` function I can't make `SumType` of it. Now I have

```
clientTypes :: [SumType  'Haskell]
clientTypes =
  [ ...
  , mkSumType (Proxy :: Proxy (Uid a))
  ]
main :: IO ()
main = writePSTypes path (buildBridge bridge) clientTypes
```

and it says

```
• No instance for (Data.Typeable.Internal.Typeable a0)
    arising from a use of ‘mkSumType’
• In the expression: mkSumType (Proxy :: Proxy (Uid a))
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Is giving `Uid a` a concrete type, i.e. `mkSumType (Proxy :: (Uid ())` possible/helpful?

Comment: It's hard to say how it should be fixed because it's unclear what you're trying to accomplish. Polymorphic types do not have `Typeable` instances, and the `SumType` datatype does not support polytypes (so you cannot even bypass the Typeable requirement of `mkSumType`).

Comment: `Proxy` itself is a polykinded type, so you can do `Proxy Uid` instead of `Proxy (Uid a)`. However, functions cannot be polykinded, which means that the `mkSumType` function is "frozen" to accept only `Proxy * a` and cannot accept `Proxy (* -> *) a`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[TypeParameters](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/purescript-bridge-0.11.0.0/docs/Language-PureScript-Bridge-TypeParameters.html) module can be used for this purpose. Simply adding

```
import Language.PureScript.Bridge.TypeParameters (A)

clientTypes :: [SumType  'Haskell]
clientTypes =
  [ ...
  , mkSumType (Proxy :: Proxy (Uid A))
  ]
```

will make the job done.